# How to give a Chrome extension permissions to "chrome.commands"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm having no luck trying to get Chrome's keyboard shortcuts for extensions working

I have this in manifest.json

```
"commands": {
    "test_command": {
        "suggested_key": {
            "windows": "Alt+Z",
            "mac": "Alt+Z",
            "chromeos": "Alt+Z",
            "linux": "Alt+Z"
          }
    }
},
"permissions": [
    "tabs"
]
```

And directly took the JavaScript from google's sample code:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
  console.log('onCommand event received for message: ', command);
});
```

But I'm still getting an error in the console on the latest stable build Chrome v28

> chrome.commands is not available: You do not have permission to access this API. Ensure that the required permission or manifest property is included in your manifest.json. [VM] binding (25):216
>   Binding.generate

And this error on Chrome Canary v30

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onCommand' of undefined`

I also tried loading the extension both by `Load Unpacked Extension`, and by packing it and dragging it into the Extensions page, neither works.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your `onCommand` listener defined in a content script? It probably won't work there; you need to include it in a background page or an action popup.

Comment: but if I want to add it to  content script?